# write element with attribute xml php

Tags: php, xml

I am writing xml using php. I want to write attribute with element. My code is as below

```
$writer = new XMLWriter();  
$writer->openURI('php://output');   
$writer->startDocument('1.0','UTF-8');   
$writer->setIndent(4);   
$writer->startElement('Response');
$writer->writeElement("Dial","+111111111");
$writer->endElement();
$writer->endDocument();   
$writer->flush();
```

This produces this output

```
<response>
<dial>+111111</dial>
</response>
```

But I want something like this

```
<response>
<dial action="myaction">+111111</dial>
</response>
```

I tried this

```
$writer->writeAttribute('action', 'myaction');
```

But this added only with startElement not with writeElement.
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead line `$writer->writeElement("Dial","+111111111");` you should write the element in some steps to add attribute

```
$writer->startElement("Dial");
$writer->writeAttribute('action', "myaction");
$writer->text("+111111111");
$writer->endElement();
```

**[demo on eval.in](https://eval.in/788267)**